# How to create a context Menu in dojo .or how to create a pop up menu when we right click on browser with the help of dojo dijit

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to create a context menu only on selected template and not on whole window, but the problem I'm facing is if I make `forwindow` as false it does not display rightClick menu and error comes as

> dojo/parser::parse() error TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null...

please help me in creating the context menu only for selected row as input name type......

```
<div>     
<input id="${name}" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox" checked='true'  data-dojo-attach-point='layerCheckBox'/>
<label for="${name}">${name}</label>
```

Here the checkbox are geeting created for different name i want on each checkbox one contextMenu

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Menu" data-dojo-props="contextMenuForWindow:false"style="display: none;" targetNodeIds= ["${name}"]  selector="row" >
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem"  data-dojo-attach-event="onClick: editLayer">Edit</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What you search is the 1st example on the dojo documentation website... You should start by that...
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Menu.html

Answer (score 0):

All `dijit/menu` properties should be defined in the attribute `data-dojo-props` :

```
<div 
   data-dojo-type="dijit/Menu" 
   data-dojo-props="contextMenuForWindow:false,targetNodeIds:['${name}'],selector:'.dom-layer-row'" 
   style="display: none;"
>
```

Comment: my bad, should be `:` instead of `=`

Comment: now the error has changed to TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null please sir help me

Comment: This can be a template issue but you haven't shared enough to see. Can you create a jsfiddle ?